# Find out which column is selected in a QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

I have a QTableWidget with `SelectionMode` set to `SingleSelection`, and `SelectionBehavior` set to `SelectColumns`. This means that **only a single column** can be selected.

But I later need to find out which column is selected, and the only functions I can use are `selectedIndexes()` or `selectedItems()`, both of which return entire lists, **which is wasteful**.

Is there a way to do this more efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the function [selectedRanges()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html#selectedRanges) does what I need. It returns a list of the selected ranges, but since it's a single column, this list would have only one item (so it's efficient, no big list need to be created).

```
int column = ui->tableWidget->selectedRanges().front().leftColumn();
```

Answer (score 3):

Your approach with the selectedItems() was correct.
As QT cant know that you've set your widget to singlerow/column selection it offers those functions to return a `QList<>`.

in your case you can work on those by using `.first()`.

Evne though I suggest to use the signals `currentColumnChanged()` to react in your application

( http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qitemselectionmodel.html#currentColumnChanged )

you could always iterate over all columns of the selected row via `selectionModel()->isColumnSelected()`

( http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qitemselectionmodel.html#isColumnSelected )

Comment: I guess using `currentColumnChanged()` would be the most efficient.

Comment: most deffinatly, just keep in mind if your code sets the column somewhere the signal gets fired too ( afaik only qts `reset()` does not fire that signal)

Answer (score 1):

```
connect(tableWidget, SIGNAL(currentCellChanged(int,int,int,int), this, SLOT(onCellChanged(int,int,int,int)));

void Class::onCellChanged(int curRow, int curCol, int preRow, int preCol)
{
    current_Col = curCol;
    // curRow, preRow and preCol are unused
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
connect(tableWidget->selectionModel()
        , SIGNAL(currentColumnChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex))
        , SLOT(onColumnChanged(QModelIndex)));

...

void Class::onColumnChanged(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    int col = index.column();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

currentColumn() returns an int of the current selected column.